# How to change or specify font-size in jeasyui datagrid?

Tags: jquery, datagrid

DataGrid from jeasy-ui has its own set of font-size for table header and table body data.

I have 3 DataGrids but i need to have default font-size for 2 DataGrids but for 1 DataGrid i have to specify the font-size explicity.

How can i do this?

```
<table class="easyui-datagrid" data-options="singleSelect:true,fitColumns:true" style="height:180px;" id="alertDescDG"> 
    <thead> 
        <tr> 
            <th data-options="field:'label', width:200"></th> 
            <th data-options="field:'value', width:200"></th> 
        </tr> 
    </thead> 
</table>
```

Comment: Please try it yourself and post the code you are in trouble.. and we'll try to help you

Comment: <table class="easyui-datagrid" data-options="singleSelect:true,fitColumns:true" style="height:180px;" id="alertDescDG">  
        <thead>  
         <tr>  
          <th data-options="field:'label', width:200"></th>  
          <th data-options="field:'value', width:200"></th>  
         </tr>  
        </thead>       
</table>

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap data in `<span>` tags, according to [this post from the easyui forum](http://www.jeasyui.com/forum/index.php?topic=4048.0).:)

```
<table class="easyui-datagrid" title="Basic DataGrid" style="width:700px;height:250px">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-options="field:'itemid',width:80">Item ID</th>
            <th data-options="field:'productid',width:100"><span style="font-weight:bold">Product</span></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: really? "u can." Can you please improve your english? This site is not reddit.

Comment: The simplest way to style the column title is to wrap a <span> element around the title. (sorry for my pool English at previous reply )

Answer (score 0):

simply add it to the style attribute:

```
style="font-size:24px;"
```

or in ems:

```
style="font-size:1.5em;"
```

Comment: adding font-size in style is not doing any change. Please Help me to resolve it.